# Is there any way to optimize the macOS Sierra Screen Share application when accessing a LINUX VNC?

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing

Is there any way to optimize the macOS Sierra Screen Share application for a LINUX VNC?  It's so much slower when compared to a connection from an iMac to another MacBook.

Comment: VNC is VNC.  How are you connecting to your Mac from the Linux box?  LAN or WAN?

Comment: Connecting via LAN.